# How to split DNS resolution per domain?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns

I would like on my Windows 10 to resolve DNS addresses on different DNS servers, based on the domain.

In practical terms, I would like `*.example.com` to be resolved by `10.10.10.10` and the rest by `10.20.30.40`.

**Is there a native solution for this problem?**

On a Linux I would have installed `dnsmasq` (or any other capable DNS server), point my resolver to 127.0.0.1 and let `dnsmasq` make the decision. On Windows 10 I saw that [`deadwood`](https://maradns.samiam.org/deadwood/) could be a solution but

- there may be a native solution
- or an alternate, better one

Comment: If you want to do this locally on your computer, and its only a handful of domains, consider editing your hosts file.

Comment: It's a bad practice to have top-level DNS-server in the network when the network is not isolated from Inet. Make 10.20.30.40 a parent for 10.10.10.10 and use the last one only. 10.10.10.10 will resolve *.example.com using local zone for that domain and forward all another queries to 10.20.30.40.

Comment: @LPChip: you mean mapping the names in `example.com` to IPs in the hosts file? If so this is not a solution in my case as the names are dynamic (`dnsmasq` is used in `example.com` to allocate the IPs via DHCP and at the same time register them in its DNS functionality).

Comment: @Akina: thanks but the architecture of the networks do not allow for that. I control `example.com`  and its `10.10.10.10` resolver but not `10.20.30.40`. So far this is not yet an issue in your proposition, but then `example.com` does not see `10.20.30.40`. An analogy of the situation I am in would be a corporate network in which the user would be (resolving everything via `10.20.30.40` and (split) VPNing into another network (`example.com`), and having the need to resolve internal `example.com` addresses via `10.10.10.10`

Comment: I wouldn't trust any native solutions on Windows-10 that has DNS leaking issue. IMHO a solution for your case is to install native version of [unbound](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/download/) for windows. It can work as a forwarder or resolve names starting from root DNS. Very decent program for Unix based OS as well for Windows.

Comment: @Alex: I used to use `deadwood` and after typing the question I had a look at the DNS servers which were available and maintained. I found `unbound`, installed it in a moment (there was just one problem which may be a documentation issue, or the way that resolver works) and it is great. So your suggestion is very good (mind to turn it into an answer so that I can accept it?)

Comment: I'm glad you like it, I moved my suggestion to the answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't trust any native solutions on Windows-10 because of its DNS leaking issue. IMHO a solution for your case is to install native version of [`unbound`](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/) for windows. It can work as a forwarder or resolve names starting from root DNS. Very decent program for Unix based OS as well for Windows.

For your case you can use following configuration:

```
server:
...
...
forward-zone:
    name: "example.com"
    forward-addr: 10.10.10.10

forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-addr: 10.20.30.40
```

Also, make sure to supply IPv6 addresses or if you don't use it, disable it in network adapter IPv6 and what is most importantly, - disable `teredo` IPv4-to-IPv6 tunnel since it can influence networking.

You can download windows version of `unbound` [here](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/download/)